# Invoke-Webrequest host variable, Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I'm trying to do an api call to a webservice and not sure what goes wrong.
Could be the quotation that is wrong in the `$request` variable.

```
[string]$subKey = "AAAAA-BBBBB-FFFFFF-EEEEEE-DDDDD"
[string]$method = "GET"
[string]$searchParam = "Type"
[string]$searchQuery = "QQ"
$request=("""https://api.test.com/api/assets/search?" + $searchParam + "=" + $searchQuery + "&PageSize=10&Page=1"""+" -Headers @{""Authorization"""+"="""+"SubKey "+$subKey+"""}")

Invoke-WebRequest $request -Method Get
```

This results in:

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

If I just copy the output of `$request` and run `Invoke-WebRequest` it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the brackets? `()`

Comment: Also - your headers need to be passed using the `-Headers` switch, not in the request URI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet takes an `-Uri` and a `-Headers` parameter. Also you can simplify the URL:

```
[string]$subKey = "AAAAA-BBBBB-FFFFFF-EEEEEE-DDDDD"
[string]$method = "GET"
[string]$searchParam = "Type"
[string]$searchQuery = "QQ"
$uri= "https://api.test.com/api/assets/search?$searchParam=$searchQuery&PageSize=10&Page=1"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization ="SubKey $subKey"} -Method Get
```

Comment: Thanks that was simple :D

Answer (score 3):

For those who may have ended up here due to an issue unrelated to OP's, this may be useful:

Remove quotes from your URL string. Literally:

```
$url = ($url -replace '"', "")
```

Specific scenario: trying to get a repo's latest release dynamically, I retrieved URL strings from GitHub API, querying the JSON with `jq` in PowerShell (an express ticket to Windows Quote Hell) and ended up with quote-inclusive strings.